# Finding the sum of characters in a text box

Tags: vb6

I have a text box with characters got from a calculation in my code . the textbox specifically contains only integers... Is there a way I can sum up the integers in the text box? Eg. If my textbox has 123456, the code should find the sum of 1+2+3+4+5+6 and then display the sum in another text box. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First, vb6 and vb.net are two different things, which do you mean? Second, what have you tried to solve this? If you have some code please post it and describe what part of it is not working as well as exactly how it is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What happens if you have a double digit number?

Comment: Please read providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6

```
Public Sub Calculate()
    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim sum     As Integer
    Dim length  As Integer
    i = 1
    sum = 0
    length = Len(TextBox1.Text)

    While i <= length
        sum = sum + Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    TextBox2.Text = sum
End Sub
```

Comment: This code gives me a Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch  highlighting the part with sum=sum+Mid(TextBox1.Text,i,1)

Answer (score -1):

Use Mid$() and Len() functions to retrieve number by number and add it (+) to the Total (sum).

**EDIT**:

```
Dim total As Integer, i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(Trim$(Text1.Text))
    total = total + CInt(Mid$(Text1.Text, i, 1))
Next i
Text2.Text = total
```

Comment: However, the code of Visual Studio Guy also work correctly.